# Can we use multiple objectdatasource in detailsview

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Good morning!  Just want to ask, can we use multiple objectdatasource in detailsview?

Example, i have 2 different tables with same fields.

Insert, Update much work properly.

Thanks,

Link

Answer (score 0):

You may add more than one `ObjectDataSource` controls in your page  but you can use only one at a time.